# Maximize Tensorflow Performance

Tags: performance, tensorflow

I'm using Tensorflow 1.2. for image segmentation on an AWS p2 instance (Tesla K80). Is there an easy way for me to find out if I can improve the performance of my code?

Here is what I know:

- I measured the execution time of the various parts of my program and
  99% of the time is spent calling session run.

> sess.run([train_op, loss, labels_modified, output_modified],
>   feed_dict=feed_dict)

where feed_dict is a mapping from placeholders to tensors.

- The session.run method only takes 0.43 seconds to execute for the following parameters: batch_size=1, image_height=512, image_width=512, channels=3.
- The network has 14 convolutional layers (no dense layers) with a total of 11 million trainable parameters.
- Because I'm doing segmentation I use a batch size of 1 and then compute the pixel-wise loss (512*512 cross entropy losses).
- I tried to compile Tensorflow from source and got zero performance improvements.

I read through the performance guide https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide but I don't want to spend a lot of time trying all of these suggestions. It already took me 8 hours to compile Tensorflow and it gave me zero benefits!

How can I find out which parts of the session run take most of the time? I have a feeling that it might be the loss calculation.

And is there any clear study that shows how much speedup I can expect from the things mentioned in the performance guide?

Answer (score 0):

You're performing a computationally intensive task that requires a lot of calculations and a lot of memory. Your model has a lot of parameters and each one requires to be computed forward, backward and updated.

The suggestions in the page you linked are OK and if you followed them all there's nothing else you can do, except creating another (1 or more) instance and run the train in parallel. This will give you a Nx speed up (where N is the number of instances that compute the gradients for your input batch) but it's extremely expensive and not always applicable (moreover it requires to change you code in order to make it follow the client-server architecture for the gradient computation and weight updates)

Comment: Yes but given that I spend a lot of time compiling Tensorflow with zero improvements I was wondering if there is a way I can find out how much speedup I will get from the other methods. 

Either: A web form that tells me: With that GPU and that input dimension the best you can get is 0.4 seconds per sample. 

Or: A tool that can tell me which parts of the session.run() take the most time (weight update, loss calculation, ...)

Comment: If you find out that your loss is the term that takes more time what would you do? The loss is defining the problem you're trying to solve. If your loss is computationally expensive you could you try to replace it with some mathematically equivalent term that requires less computation time, it's true. But you also have to be sure that your change won't impact the definition of your solution (the loss). However, I don't know any tool/web form that can help you. Since it's everything extremely task-dependent I don't think that it exists (and if exists how reliable it is)

Comment: Alright, will try to maybe just use a simple loss for timing purpose. I was hoping there are tables where people report the speedups on a classical image classification problem and a comparable architecture. Guess I'm not lucky though.

Comment: It depends a lot by the hardware used and the problem. You know, guys at Facebook can train a network on image-net in an hour.. But there are few other companies in the world that have such a great amount of GPUs :D

Comment: That's why I specifically said it's a tesla k80 ;) I'm sure this is what the majority of people use these days.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can run your code with [tfprof](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/tfprof) to do some profiling to find out where the bottleneck is.

For just guessing, the performance problem may caused by feeding data. Don't how did you prepare your feed_dict, if you have to read you data from disk for preparing your feed_dict for every sess.run, it will slow the program for reading data and training is in synchronous. you can try to covert you data to tfrecords, make loading data and training in asynchronous by using tf.FIFOQueue

Comment: Thanks, will give tfprof a try!

Regarding feeding data: All my data is in memory and I just generate the samples on the fly. No disk usage what so ever. Also filling the dict takes 0.1% of the time (1/1000th times less than the sess.run() call).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your small piece of code, I see you're using a feed dictionary. Generally it's best to avoid using feed dictionaries if queues can be used (see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2919). The Tensorflow documentation covers the use of queues [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues). Switching to queues will definitely improve your performance.

Comment: Yes but they recently improved the additional copy overhead and filling the dictionary takes only 0.1% of the time according to my measurements. Might still be worth it but converting my code will take quite a lot of time :/